# How to handle custom html tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, custom-tags

I'm being given HTML that has custom tags for glossary entries, for example:   
and

I was thinking I could automatically replace this with a `a href` however, it's not working as expected.

Based on the answers so far I have modified things a bit now I have this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
  $( "glo" ).each(function(index){  
 var x = ( $( this ).attr("name") );
  link = document.createElement("a"); 
  link.setAttribute('href', '../../QA-C/Messages/Glossary.html#' + x);
  var y = ($( this).text());
    $(this).html('');
    link.innerHTML = y;
    $("glo")[index].prepend(link);
        });
    });
});
 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

   <p>
            <p>
            <glo name ="size_t">size_t</glo> is defined by a typedef in the standard library header files <code class="nm">&lt;stdio.h&gt;, &lt;stddef.h&gt;, &lt;stdlib.h&gt;, &lt;string.h&gt;</code> and <code class="nm">&lt;time.h&gt;</code>.
</p>
        <p>
QA C has an option (-intrinsictype), which allows the type associated with <i>size_t</i> to be configured.
Message 0040 is generated if a <i>typedef</i> encountered in the source code is not consistent with this configured type.
</p>
        <p>
The <glo name="QA_C.Standard.Library.header.files">QA_C.Standard.Library.header.files</glo> use an implicit macro, <i>PRQA_SIZE_T</i>, when declaring the type of <i>size_t</i>.
This macro is automatically defined in the QA C environment to reflect the configuration option setting.
If you are using your own header files to define <i>size_t</i>, you should ensure that QA C is configured to be consistent with this typedef.
</p>

</p>
<p>
<glo name="size_t">size for size_t</glo> some text to test
</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

so this works but I am sure there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:custom-tags], so presumably the custom tags you are talking about don't appear in the browser and you need to look at the output of your JSP to see what the HTML really looks like.

Comment: "not working as expected" — What do you expect? How does what you get differ from that? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: And can you please paste your `html` too

Comment: The custom tags are in the source that I am using to generate Message text for my Help system. They are internaly used to link to glossary entries, i need to cange them into links to my html glossary.

Comment: @BrianCoughlin — The JSP source? Or, when you said [tag:custom-tags], did you mean straight up invalid HTML and not JSP's [tag:custom-tags]? Or maybe you have an XML document and not an HTML document? (Provide a [mcve]!)

Comment: they are straightup invalid HTML really ...

Comment: You don't need the `'</a>'`, since it is part of the wrapper.

Comment: Then fix the tags on your question. (And they are invalid in a completly broken way. `<foo />` is a **start tag**, not a whole element. The text following it is **inside** the element. Your document is just broken. I'd fix it on the server).

Comment: I have fixed the invalid HTMl and got something working but I am sure there must be a more elegant way to do this